# Sync fusion Xamarin forms standard entry/editor

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I’m enjoying the control suite from sync fusion for their auto complete and numeric editor. Just wanting a standard text entry and a multi line entry but there doesn’t seem to be any in their controls, unless I’m missing something?

The main problem is when I go and use the base entry and editor controls with Xamarin forms they totally look and behave differently and make it look quite jarring in the app so want to find these standard controls to keep it the same through out the app.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Well the point of using Xamarin forms is to pretty much make the app look native to the user, anyways what you are looking for is easily achievable using custom renderers